# XML - How to place child node in center of parent node

Tags: php, xml

So I have this xml:

```
<al>
A

    <extref>EXTREF1</extref>
B

    <extref>EXTREF2</extref>
C

</al>
```

If I do:

```
echo $xml->al;
```

the result is:

```
A B C
```

instead of

```
A EXTREF1 B EXTREF2 C
```

How can I get the  links to show at the correct position?
I know you can get the 'extref' using a foreach with:

```
$xml->al->extref
```

But how can I place them in the right position ?
I'm using SimpleXML

Comment: what do you mean by the "correct position", exactly? Position in relation to what? Are you asking how to pretty-print the XML? Or how to output the elements in a certain order?

Comment: Changed the XML to something more clear but it still has the same goal.

Comment: The [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) returned by [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) contains all the elements on their correct positions. You can use `print_r($xml)` to check. `echo()` is not the tool to print a `SimpleXMLElement` object. You have to walk through it and decide what to print and what not.

Comment: Is `echo $xml->al->asXML();` more what your after?

Answer (score 0):

The [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) returned by [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) contains all the elements on their correct positions. You can use `print_r($xml)` to check. `echo()` is not the tool to print a `SimpleXMLElement` object. You have to walk through it and decide what to print and what not.

But, if you want to print all the XML text nodes, in the order they appear in the XML structure, you can use [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to brute-force remove everything that looks like an XML tag and print what it returns.

It is not quite the recommended method to process an XML file, though.